Can we select specific scenarios to run in cucumber tests?
I want to choose which scenarios to run using testNG.xml file, like I need to add certain scenarios in specific suit and decide which suite to run; for example I need to make a regression suit that contains some scenarios and another suite that covers certain module in the application then decide which one to run based on my need knowing that some scenarios may be common among some suites.
is that possible to be done through testNG.xml file?
Thank you
I tried to make java application to select scenarios from a GUI and it was successful but when the number of scenarios becomes big it through and exception that the command is too long
and tags is not suitable for me as the scenarios may be common among suits even if we can tag the same scenario multiple times it will be unorganized to give the same scenario 5 or higher tags
so if can we do this like in selenium using testNG.xml file?

You'll want to read: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-testng#configure-cucumber-options-via-testng-xml and https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-core#properties-environment-variables-system-options

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
